# jQuery Display Horizontal Scale Multiple Marker

Tags: jquery

I am looking for jQuery Solution to display the 4 values on a horizontal scale line. The values are Minimum, Maximum, Average, and Current. It is not a 2 Dimensional Graph. Just a simple 4 points on a single horizontal line with the markers pointing to those points.

To show what I am trying to achieve, here is a sketch

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that came to my mind was the [jQuery UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/). It supports multiple handles, and you can make it disabled if its for display purposes only.

```
$(function() {
    $mySlider = $("#slider-range");
    $mySlider.slider({

      min: 0,
      max: 1000,
      values: [ 75, 125, 175, 225 ],
      slide: function( evt, ui ) {
          a = [];
          for(var i=0; i<ui.values.length; i++) {
              a.push(ui.values[i]);
          }

          $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + a.join(" - " + "$") );
      }
    });

    $( "#amount" ).val(
      ["$" + $mySlider.slider("values", 0),
       "$" + $mySlider.slider("values", 1),
       "$" + $mySlider.slider("values", 2),
       "$" + $mySlider.slider("values", 3)].join(" - ")
    );
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5TTm4/583/)

Comment: that was the first thing I checked but I did not find a way to display more than 2 handles on that. Do you know the exact syntax which I can use to do that.

Comment: Thanks Johan, The only issue left is how to display the labels for each marker, Also is there a way to display the scale markings. In the API I did not find the way to display the labels for the markers.

Comment: @VinayJain I don't think there is something built in for that. I suggest using absolute positioned divs with styling of your choice.

Comment: Thanks Johan, I searched for some other posts in stackoverflow and I was able to achieve that. I really appreciate all the help. I think I am good now.

Answer (score 0):

check out [jQuery Slider plugin](http://egorkhmelev.github.com/jslider/), i think it will suit your needs and will be implemented easily.

**EDIT**

To make it read only you can position a transparent element on top of the slider, thus preventing the user from moving it manually.

Comment: I looked at the jQuery Slider plug in but was not able to figure out how to make it readonly and also how to show more that 2 markers, I want this for display purpose only and do not want the user to move the sliders